Assembler - Arrival Table Should be Sorted by Arrival Date in Increasing Order
Ok, I don't know if this is a real modeling issue, or my model is just completely corrupted. In my model I have two Source blocks going directly into an Assembler block. Bother sources are defined by tables named booster_table and be4 I have quadruple checked and both tables are organized with the arrival date column in ascending order. However, as soon as the agent created by the table be4 enters the table, I get the error:
Model logic error:

root.boosterArrival:
Arrival table should be sorted by arrival date in increasing order. Please use Database View on the table with ordering.

Again, the table feeding boosterArrival is in ascending order and the error happens on the same day that the be4 agent enters the assembly block. When I toggle the Quantity field to 0 to not require a be4 agent the error goes away. This seems like completely illogical behavior and makes me think my model is dead.
Here is an image of how this part of my model is set up.
Sources and Assembler

well, a screen of the table would be good. Then start Sherlocking: reduce the table size, just do 2 rows sorted, 1 row, 100 rows. Still an error?

Ok, so I've figured this out, but still not entirely sure why the solution works. I added a queue block to act as a buffer between the source and assembler and everything works fine now. My theory is that the source block is not capable of synchronizing the output to the assembler block and is sending agents in an unexpected order, but I have not been able to find any such claims in the AnyLogic documentation or here on other forum posts.
